# How to read the elements based on other element value + xslt?

Tags: xml, vb.net, xslt

I have the below xml, I want to select the value of savings element when the Name element value is "Total"

How can I write the xslt for this particular scenario?

```
</ArrayOfCategoryData>
    <CategoryData>
      <Category>
       <Category>
         <Savingsdollar>0.00</Savingsdollar>
         <Savingspercentage>0.00</Savingspercentage>
         <Savingsusage>0.00</Savingsusage>
       </Category>
      </Category>
     <Name>Refrigeration</Name>
    </CategoryData>
  <CategoryData>
     <Category>
      <Category>
        <Savingsdollar>999.97</Savingsdollar>
        <Savingspercentage>0.00</Savingspercentage>
        <Savingsusage>9,998.04</Savingsusage>
      </Category>
     </Category>
    <Name>Total</Name>
  </CategoryData>
</ArrayOfCategoryData>




 <table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
                  <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td style='border-left: none; border-bottom: none; width: 51px;'>
                          $ <xsl:value-of select="//ArrayOfCategoryData/CategoryData[Name='Total']//Savingsdollar/text()"/>
                        </td>
                        <td style='border-bottom: none; width: 29px;'>
                          <xsl:value-of select="//ArrayOfCategoryData/CategoryData[Name='Total']//Savingspercentage/text()"/>%
                        </td>
                        <td style='border-bottom: none;'>
                          <xsl:value-of select="//ArrayOfCategoryData/CategoryData[Name='Total']//Savingsusage/text()"/>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: You mean xpath? `/CategoryData[Name='Total']//Savings/text()`

Comment: Yes I need xpath or somehow I want to get that savings value from xslt, I copied the same that you have given it is not showing me the value 9.998.04 with this expression

Comment: I have placed my actual xml file , now please give me a xpath or any condition to read the any savings element value of the "Total" Name element.

Comment: Based on your new XML, your target node has changed to `Savingsusage`. Just change `Savings` to `Savingsusage`.

Comment: Joel, I tried this once but not able to read that svingsdollar 
value          //ArrayOfCategoryData/CategoryData[Name='Total']//Savingsdollar/text()

Comment: Maybe you have a default namespace in your XML file. Do you see xmlns="" somewhere?

Comment: above I placed my xslt even, which is not reading those savings values

Comment: It is clear here that the xpath is correct (http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaFr/1).

Answer (score 1):

If I apply this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="text()"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CategoryData[Name='Total']">
    <Total>
        <xsl:value-of select="Category/Savings"/>
    </Total>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to your source XML I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Total>9,998.04</Total>
```

Try around a bit with the XSLT I gave you

Comment: Peter, I am unable to call <xsl:template> within the table elements , I placed xslt above please help me how to read within the table td elemets

Comment: I am not very familiar with XSTL in connection with HTML tables. I suggest you open a new question with source XML, XSLT and expected output. Best regards, Peter